# Jira: Tracking work for a feature which is done in different versions of components

Tags: project-management, jira

We build a product which consists of few components. As we plan to release a new version of the project with some new features we break down work into sub-tasks in relevant components and plan for versions of components. Some sub-tasks (such as integration testing) remain in product's version though.

It is somewhat difficult to track progress on the feature as Jira appears to lack means of tracking such projects.
I created list of products versions and list of versions for each of the components.

I wish I had burn down chart of remaining work for sprint/release scope done in multiple Jira versions. Or some other tools to visualize feature development progress product wide.

I was looking for some way to export worklogs to build chart in Excel but had no luck so far. I could use some advice on using Jira for such projects. Thank you

Comment: Just to make sure , are you looking for a way to export filtered data from Jira to Excel format? selected fields from selected issues?

Comment: Nope, I need to export worklogs on issues NOT the issues

Answer (score 0):

this is a jira tool to visualize any collection of features you want : forecast.geertjan.it/  It allows you to monitor the progress of features per sprint/week. The list is based on your own filter.